# Naming splash screen files for IOS in config.xml (Phonegap)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cordova, phonegap-build

We are using phonegap for our app and now we are adding the splash screens in the conig.xml, but we are a bit confuse after reading the IOS and Phonegap documentations about the names of the files.

Phonegap documentations says:

```
<gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" /><gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default_at_2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960"/>
<gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default_iphone5.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
<gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="748" />
<gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1004" />

<!-- retina iPad support: PhoneGap 2.5.0+ only -->
<gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Landscape_at_2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1496" />
<gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Portrait_at_2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2008" />
```

And IOS documentation says that:

```
<basename><usage_specific_modifiers><scale_modifier><device_modifier>.png
```

> Default-568h@2x~iphone.png (640x1136 pixels)
>   Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png (2048x1496 pixels)
>   Default-Landscape~ipad.png (1024x748 pixels)
>   Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png (1536x2008 pixels)
>   Default-Portrait~ipad.png (768x1004 pixels) Default@2x~iphone.png
>   (640x960 pixels) Default~iphone.png (320x480 pixels)

Should we rename the names in the config.xml as IOS documentation says or is phonegap build who does it?

Thanks!

Comment: No need to change splash image if your creating project using terminal. Automatically splash image and launcher icon name created on that current version. And I checked now there is no reference for splashscreen in config.xml while creating project using terminal. works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap build does it. That is my compilation (rename 
.ipa to .zip) from phonegap build and I didnt have those names in my checked in code . . .

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That helped... but Phonegap build is not deploying some icons that are recomended by Apple, see the issue here: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/missing_recommended_icon_file